# find and replace text in file recursively in linux

Tags: linux, sed

I am in need to find and replace a part of text in all my files on my web server. I am aware of the command (by Google'ing it) as

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} +
```

Problem though is that the text I need to replace contains `/` in it. For instance I need to...

Find

```
/home/this/root/
```

With

```
/home/that/root/
```

since the command above uses `/` as a separator to determine `find/replace` how do I include `/` in my search so the command does not get confused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different sed delimiter.

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's~foo~bar~g' {} +
```